# Where will the reducer output save in Hadoop is it in Client node or in HDFS

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to set output path as per the client node,

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    String[] otherArgs = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args).getRemainingArgs();
    if (otherArgs.length != 2) {
        System.err.println("Usage: wordcount <in> <out>");
        System.exit(2);
    }
    Job job = new Job(conf, "word count");
    job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);
    job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);
    job.setCombinerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
    job.setReducerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[1]));

    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
}
```

But it's always referring to HDFS. eg. `FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[1]));`

How can I get the file on the client using map reduce? I know we can achieve this with the `copyToLocal` command. But I'm wondering if there is a way to pipe the reducer output straight away to the client Local File directory. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

In a multinode hadoop cluster, the reduce tasks corresponding to a mapreduce job can execute in any of the nodes. So if you are adding a logic to write the output of reducer directly to local instead of hdfs, it may get saved in some of the nodemanager or tasktracker nodes. If you have only one node, you can implement the write to local logic in the reducer class. But this is not a good logic.

If you really need the output in the local directory of client machine, then performing copyToLocal to the client/edge node using api will be the best approach.